# How to show $2c_1 > c_2$ in Chebyshev's estimates for $\pi(x)$ to prove Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I would like to show that if

$$ c_1\frac{x}{\ln(x)} < \pi(x) < c_2 \frac{1}{\ln(x)}  \hspace{1cm} \text{  (Chebyshev's Estimates)} $$

then

$$ \pi(2x) - \pi(x) > 1   \hspace{1cm} \text{  (Bertrand's Postulate)}  $$

only if

$$ 2c_1 > c_2 $$

Although I suspect this question is about algebraic manipulation, the context is the Chebyshev estimates for the prime counting function being sufficiently narrow to prove Bertrand's Postulate (eg [pdf](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Efranz/nt/cheb.pdf)) where:

$$\begin{align} c_1 &= \frac12 \ln(2) \\\\c_2 &= 6\ln(2)\end{align}$$

---

My own attempts only take me as far as the following:

The smallest difference $\pi(2x) - \pi(x)$ is when we consider the lower bound for $\pi(2x)$ and the upper bound for $\pi(x)$.

$$ c_1\frac{2x}{\ln(2x)} - c_2\frac{x}{\ln(x)} > 1 \hspace{1cm} \text{  (Bertrand's Postulate)}$$

From this I can't make progress.

Comment: You will need better values for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: If I aim for $\pi(2x) - \pi(x) > 0$ the algebra takes me to $(2c_1 - c_2) \ln x > c_1 \ln 2 $ from which we can say that $(2c_1 - c_2)$ needs to be positive and so the desired conclusion. But this isn't the $>1$ constraint we really want.

Comment: It is enough to show $\pi(2x)-\pi(x)>0$ because the LHS is an integer, so this implies $\pi(2x)-\pi(x)\geq 1$.

Comment: hi @gary thanks, that is helpful. It seems then the proof is complete based on showing that $(2c_1 - c_2)>0$. For the given values of $c_1, c_2$ this doesn't work as you say. are you aware of other proofs, accessible to pre-university students, that give tighter bounds $c_1, c_2$?

Comment: There is a proof by Erdős (https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1932-01.pdf) that gives a positive lower bound directly for $\pi(2x)-\pi(x)$.

Comment: Thanks @Gary. - I've written up my walk-through of Lemmermayer's note https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com/2021/04/chebyshevs-estimates-for-pix.html. Any errors are mine, and I'd welcome thoughts, corrections.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. It would imply $\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}$ for large $x$. What you can say is that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $x_0$ such that the inequalities are true with $c_1 =1-\varepsilon$ and $c_2=1+\varepsilon$ whenever $x>x_0$.

Comment: @Gary - For my own certainty, is it this statement "Other work by Chebyshev, and others, showed that the true form has $c_1=c_2=1$" ? If so, yes I agree, this statement is wrong as it implies equality rather than asymptotic equivalence to $1/\ln(x)$. I will change it. Thank you .. this is a real journey of learning for me!

Comment: @Gary one last comment: That $c_1, c_2$ can be as close to 1 as desired, for large enough $x$, is a statement of the Prime Number Theorem? But Chebyshev didn't prove the PNT so I am missing something. Most texts say that Chebyshev proved the limit is 1, if the limit exists, but he didn't prove the limit exists. Is this the gap?

Comment: Yes, that is the sentence I ment. Indeed, Chebyshev showed that if the limit $(\pi(x)\log x)/x$ as $x\to +\infty$ exists, it must be $1$. The hard part was to show that the limit exists which he could not do. And yes, the fact that $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be arbitrarily close to $1$ for sufficiently large $x$ is the statement of the PNT.